# Execute SAS Stored Process Via SAS Portal

Tags: html, sas

I have here a simple SAS Stored Process that basically upload excel file to the server.
However, upon clicking OK button on the first attempt, the page is redirecting to the SAS Stored Process Web Application site. When I tried to refresh the SAS Portal and upload again the same file and click OK button, the code is working properly which is returned in the same page.

I am not so familiar with the HTML code if I missed out something  or I put correct value on the form statement.

Thanks for the help :)

```
data _null_;
file _webout;
put '<form action="/SASStoredProcess/do?_program=/CMS Portal/STP/upload_excel_common" 
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input type="hidden" name="_program" value="/Path/StoredProcessName/"> 
<input type="hidden" name="SERVER_PATH" value="/sasdata/cmsuser/">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th align="right">Choose a file to upload:</th>
<td><input type="file" name="myfile" size="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left"></td></tr> 
</table>
</form>';

run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing HTML using data step put statements is an anti-pattern!

Far better to write Javascript that calls SAS.  We have built an open source project that you can use for loading files onto a SAS server (be that Viya, SAS 9 or Foundation SAS) - see: https://github.com/sasjs/fileuploader

Another option (again from our team) is [Data Controller for SAS](https://datacontroller.io) - it lets you upload any version of Excel and the data will go through an approval process before landing in your target database table.

To address your question, it's probably due to a session timeout.  Your code does not have any login handling.

Comment: The login handling will be catered by the SAS Portal itself since I linked the SAS Stored Process in the SAS IDP..

Thanks for sharing the code, will look into it..